# How do I get AJV (v5.0.0) to useJSON Schema 0.7?

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I can't seem to find how to make AJV use 0.7 (or 0.6 or 0.4).  I think it's the "$schema" keyword, but I can't find a string (URI) that doesn't cause an error.

If I'm right, what is the value I should assign the keyword "$schema" that will work?

If I'm wrong, and there's some other way to indicate version, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ajv website, this is how they recommend you tell Ajv v6 to work with a non-default schema:

> Please note: To use Ajv with draft-06 schemas you need to explicitly add the meta-schema to the validator instance: [1]
>
> `ajv.addMetaSchema(require('ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-06.json'));`

If you install Ajv v5 and looks at the `lib/refs` folder, the draft-07 schema isn't available:

```
$data.json
json-schema-draft-04.json
json-schema-draft-06.json
json-schema-v5.json
```

So I don't think you can apply a similar technique to work with draft-07 with Ajv v5 and this may be the reason why you're struggling with this.

My recommendation would be to use Ajv v6 as it works with draft-07 by default:

> Ajv version 6.0.0 that supports draft-07 is released. [1]

**References**

1. https://ajv.js.org/

Comment: This is correct. The newer version of ajv supports a newer version of JSON Schema.